# Can I hide the port number in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I am setting up a corporate intranet site using WAMP and wordpress.  I have a server running IIS on port 80 and WAMP on port 8080.  I have the wordpress site running under WAMP.  I want to publish the wordpress site without the port number. 
 For example, http://MyServer/MySite rather than http://MyServer:8080/MySite.

I have tried leaving the port number out of the "Site Address (URL)" but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse proxy it in iis

you need to install URL rewrite and Application Request Rerouting ( both MS plugins )

Then make a virtual directory under your main site (at the location you want "MySite" ), and go to url rewrite and it has an option to create the reverse proxy.

[image]

This will also mean you get HTTPS if your main site has HTTPS already

and reverse proxy to where your WAMP is hosted on your server

[image]